# Keycloak Server on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, keycloak

Currently I'm working on a Spring Boot 2 project where we use Heroku as our Cloud Service. We push our changes to Github and our instance on Heroku cloud gets provisioned and deployed. After participating Javaday in my city, I attended to a speech and got to know about this amazing framework, Keycloak. After some investigation, we have decided using Keycloak as our identity and access management.

From what I understand, we need to start a Keycloak standalone server as explained here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html.
But the problem is, we cannot access to filesystem on Heroku instance and thus, cannot extract the Keycloak files and start the server.

I tried to follow these steps https://github.com/yurtsevich/keycloak-swarm-heroku yurtsevich has provided but I noticed that latest version of Keycloak Swarm is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.

Can we start Keycloak server on the same Heroku instance we have? I'm unable to find any solution to this at this moment.

Comment: Hi, do you find out if it is possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had given up on this issue back then and don't know if it's possible today.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this button from readme will deploy Keycloak on Heroku with free dynos: https://github.com/sannonaragao/keycloak-heroku

This button deploys the lastest version straight to Heroku.
https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/mieckert/keycloak-heroku

Beware! It deploys at the Performance-M dyno, you must change to free right after if you don't want to pay some use fee.

Comment: The one with free dynos doesn't do anything for me. Just redirects to Heroku, but nothing happens

Comment: @ChrisNeve, first you must be logged to Heroku, then the button in Github will redirect you to the "Create New App"  interface in Heroku, to add pwd click in deploy to build the Keycloak.